# Navigate between UITextfields after ONE character is entered, delete anytime at any place and navigate again in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift2, becomefirstresponder

I am working on 4 digit passcode, I have done lots of search about it but unfortunately I could not find relative example for swift 2.0. What I am after is to represent the user main page after 4 digit passcode is provided.

My code is copied from a objective-c example and it is not doing all functions as a wanted. What it is doing so far it is setting the responder when user enters the password it sets the next responder by using setNextResponder function.

As you can see the the shouldChangeCharactersInRange function is as follows accepts the the forward response and backspace response. However, I could not achieve the full functionality. When I say full functionality moving the cursor next UITextfield until last one and backspacing from last one to first one is fine but for example if the responder at 2nd I can not backspace or when I backspace from last one and when the responder comes to 3rd UITextfield I can not type in and move the cursor again fourth one.

You can see my ShouldCharacterChange method as below:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        let scanner = NSScanner(string:string)


        if (string.characters.count > 0 && !scanner.scanInt(nil) ){

            return false

        }


        let oldLength = textField.text!.utf16.count

        let replaceStringLength = string.characters.count

        let rangeLength = range.length

        let newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replaceStringLength

        var shouldBackspace = false

        if (newLength == 1){

            if (textField == firstFieldTextField){

   self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: secondField, afterDelay: 0.1)

                shouldBackspace = true

                print (shouldBackspace)


            } else if (textField == secondField) {



                self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: thirdField, afterDelay: 0.1)



            } else if (textField == thirdField){


                self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: fourthField, afterDelay: 0.1)



            }


        } else if (oldLength > 0  && newLength == 0) {


            if (textField == fourthField){

                self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: thirdField, afterDelay: 0.1)


            } else if (textField == thirdField){


                self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: secondField, afterDelay: 0.1)

            } else if (textField == secondField){

                self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:") ,withObject: firstFieldTextField, afterDelay: 0.1)


            }

        }


        return newLength <= 1 // Bool



    }
```

The selector of SetNextResponder function or selector is as shown:

```
 func setNextResponder(textField:UITextField){


        textField.becomeFirstResponder()


    }
```

[The video of the application can be found here for more detailed explanation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7g3kxpevu247qc7/4PasscodeEntry.mov?dl=0)

Any help will be appreciated many thanks

Comment: Why don’t you try this https://github.com/abury/ABPadLockScreen , no need to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vakas but I need to do it lik that since the UI design of the client has been designed in that way

Comment: You can customise this to suit your required UI.